# How To Hide the Contact Button and Replace with a Message

Tags: privatemsg

I'm building a room letting website.
Next to every advert is a send user private message button.

If the room is no longer available.
I want to replace the button with the message "Sorry room no longer available"
how can I do this please?

Many Thanks for your help
Charles

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hook_form_alter`. Find your form name and use the code below ([form api doc](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7)).

```
function yourmodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
if($form_id=='your_form_id'){
 hide($form['#submit']);
$form['mymessage']= array(
   '#type' => 'markup',
   '#markup' => 'sorry , no one available in room',
   '#weight' => 0,
);
}
}
```